# Why 403 Forbidden error When changing root directory of Apache to another drive?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, root

I installed apache 2.4.7 server as I switched from Windows, in which I used WAMP, so now I am using apache2 in Ubuntu I want to make old `www` directory of WAMP as the new root directory of apache2 in Ubuntu.

So I made the following changes.
(My PC username is `siraj` and name of the drive is `MINE`)

In `apache2.conf` file

```
<Directory /media/siraj/MINE/Business_Work/wamp/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

---

In `000-default.conf` file.

```
DocumentRoot /media/siraj/MINE/Business_Work/wamp/www/html

<Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Directory /media/siraj/MINE/Business_Work/wamp/www/html/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and `sudo chown -R www-data /srv/www/html`

Now the thing is, in first case localhost running well, but in second case (when changing root directory to another drive) it shows following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Here's My `apache` error log.

`(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:51063] AH00529: /media/siraj/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/media/siraj/' is executable, referer: http://localhost/`

Here's the output of command: `namei -lx /media/siraj/MINE/Business_Work/wamp/www/html/`

```
f: /media/siraj/MINE/Business_Work/wamp/www/html/
Drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  media
drwxr-x--- root  root  siraj
Drwx------ siraj siraj MINE
drwx------ siraj siraj Business_Work
drwx------ siraj siraj wamp
drwx------ siraj siraj www
drwx------ siraj siraj html
```

I've seen almost all the similar questions asked here. But didn't find what I am missing here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53944/discussion-on-question-by-siraj-why-403-forbidden-error-when-changing-root-direc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching whole day finally here's the complete solution.

As @muru told to go [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) I sum up things I found after searching in many places.

As we can't change the mod of drive using `chmod` as it is defined by partition's mount option. So we mount the target drive (`MINE` in my case) in current drive (`ext4` in my case.).

First,find the UUI and partition name table of your drive using following command

`$ sudo blkid`

Now unmount the target drive (`sda6` in my case get from the above command) using following command.

`$ sudo umount /dev/sda6`

Now type the following command to mount the target drive in current drive.

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/sda6 /srv
```

Now make the changes in **000-default.conf** and **apache2.conf** file like done in question.

That's It. Celebrate.