# how to change the place of the local server files to avoid permissions problems?

Tags: permissions, lamp, webserver, wordpress

I installed the the lamp server  on my machine and installed wordpress on it and it work ;
the problem when I upload files to the wordpress through the control panel of the wordpress no files uploaded because the permission

I found a terminal lines  used before and they succeeded in a lot of times but this time they can't make any sense
so I though about to make change the files place from var/www to my normal partitions so I will not face any problems with permissions

Any help , please ?

Comment: Who is the owner of your directories and what is the permissions set on them? You are not the first person facing with this problem. Try to solve it as it is supposed to be not in your own innovative way. Otherwise, you will open a gate for hackers

Comment: Moreover, here we can help if your question be about things related to OS such as permission. If you want to make alteration in Wordpress, that needs to asked in somewhere like: wordpress.stackexchange.com. I don't suggest to go for altering Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go through [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885340/why-403-forbidden-error-when-changing-root-directory-of-apache-to-another-drive) about changing your apache root directory to another drive.

Now you have to give permission to all users to upload files on your server in the present root directory.

Run the following command to give permission.

`sudo chmod 777 /path/to/upload/folder`.

After that you will be able to uplad files on the desired directory.